# Which memory address it prints

Tags: ios, objective-c

Which memory address it prints in each case pointer address or string(hello) address. Do help me

case:1-

```
NSString *myMessage=@"hello";
NSLog(@"my message:%p",myMessage);
```

case:2-

```
NSString *myMessage=@"hello";
NSLog(@"my message:%p",&myMessage);
```

Answer (score 2):

Case 1 -

NSString is a class...

NSString *myMessage = @"hello"; ... myMessage is a pointer to the NSString object containing "hello"

Your specific address will be different, but it's essentially this (use `p myMessage` in debug console:

```
(__NSCFConstantString *) $2 = 0x0000000103e9f150
```

Case 2 -

& gives you the address of the object

&myMessage ... means *address of the pointer to "hello"*

Your specific address will be different, but it's essentially this (use `p &myMessage` in debug console:

```
(NSString **) $3 = 0x00007fff5bd62a98
```

Comment: In summary, case 1 prints the address of the string object, case 2 prints the address of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Every variable is a memory location and every memory location has its address defined which can be accessed using ampersand (&) operator, which denotes an address in memory.

case:1-  It will print "my message:0x6011d0 "

```
NSString *myMessage=@"hello";
NSLog(@"my message:%p",myMessage);
```

output : my message: 
0x6011d0

case:2- It will return address location of variable myMessage.

```
NSString *myMessage=@"hello";
NSLog(@"my message:%p",&myMessage);
```

output : my message: 0x7ffe5a42e558

Comment: No first output mismatches there i am not returning an object token "%@" but returning pointer token "%p"                                               **NSLog(@"my message:%@",myMessage)** In this case it prints hello but not in my case-1.

Comment: @Gree Yes. Updated

Comment: This edited answer will be correct once you fix the line that says: *"output : my message: hello"*.